# attr working on desktop but not working on iPad, iphone - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery I am using to update a couple of drop down selects.

It works fine on desktop, but does nothing on Mobile.  Maybe I am configuring it wrong?

It should be looping through the options in the SELECT menu and if there is a match, then "select" that matching option.

JQuery:

```
      var timestamp= '00:00:01';     

  $( "#end option[value='" + timestamp + "']" ).each(function() {   
           $( this ).attr( 'selected','selected' );
   });
```

HTML

```
 <select id="end" name="timestamp">
 <option value="00:00:00">00:00:00</option>
 <option value="00:00:01">00:00:01</option>
 <option value="00:00:02">00:00:02</option>
 </select>
```

Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: Try `$("#end option[value='" + timestamp + "']").prop('selected', true)`. And BTW, none of your selects have that value.

Comment: Thanks @j08691  I made the edit for the values.  I used your method, but it also works fine on desktop, but iPad a no go.

Comment: Disregard.  It's all good.  Thanks!

Comment: I am having same problem . ANy solution ??