# attr title not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, attr

This is my code

```
$(this).children().attr('title');
```

This piece of code works fine on PC but not on ipad.

I tried using below codes  *(its a `<a>` tag with `class` preview)*

```
$(this).children().prop('title');

$(this).children(".preview").attr('title');

$(this).find(".preview").attr('title');

$(this).find("a").attr('title');
```

Again works on PC but not on ipad

Does  `title` `attr` does not work on ipad ??
I have a simillar issue like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863234/attr-working-on-desktop-but-not-working-on-ipad-iphone-jquery) I guess.

Note: Nothing looks wrong with the HTML / JQuery code Since I have tried with all PC browsers and even on Safari . It works fine .

Comment: Just to isolate the issue have you tried getting the title of a single element? Eg `$(this).children().first().attr('title');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Still the same . Works on PC but not on ipad . I have listed some more trials in my question.All works on PC all browsers but not on ipad

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : problem was with title attr . No idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a weird answer .
Problem was with `title` `attr` itself in ipad. I tried alerting the class of that DOM (`.preview`). It alerted on ipad too but alerting title on Ipad was going blank ,  Dont know why.

What i did now is i made a data attribute for the value I required and fetching using that

i.e.

```
$(this).children().attr('data-colorname');
```

Above Code works for Ipad too now  :|